# aspnet.friendlyurls versus Url Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, friendly-url

We're looking to ditch the old URL rewriting package we're currently using in our asp.net webforms application (UrlRewritingNet - it is out of support and development). In my research I've come across two potential replacements (I think) however I'm unclear if they are truly apples to apples in their essential functionality (as well as our existing functionality).

The first is friendlyUrls, if I add the NuGet package and get it configured, it looks like I can work with it and it will probably do all the redirecting and friendly urls that we need. It looks like it's pretty easy to use and we can code to put some routes in a DB and make it so we don't have to hard code everything into a config file.

The second is URL Rewrite 2.0 for IIS. It seems more like what we're currently using. It appears that everything is specified in the .config file. It also seems pretty involved to create rewrites.

We only have a couple of rewrites that seem that they may not be served easily by friendlyUrls (like http=>https, a 301 redirect from our old domain and a no-www => www) but it may also be I haven't looked into that aspect of friendlyUrls. (edit: Oh, and I guess we may get a request occasionally to go from a friendlyUrl to an outside website i.e. www.oursite.com/there => www.yoursite.com)

My question is, are these essentially the same thing, or am I missing something? Should I be using one, the other or both do and in what instances should I use one over the other? I can't seem to find a clear comparison of what each does/doesn't do for me, especially in comparison to the other.

Comment: You can ditch both. You can [map page routes in Web Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx). It's built into the framework. Nothing extra to add, and you get full control.

Comment: @mason Thanks for your comment, you pointed me in a good direction. It seems that the FriendlyUrl is just an extension of the routes built in to .Net (adding automatic routing) and then I would use the routes.MapPageRoute to add specific page routes. It also seems that I need some kind of rewriting though if I want to do any external changes (i.e. the old domain to new domain). Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mason Thanks for your comment, you pointed me in a good direction.

FriendlyUrl is just an extension of the routes built in to .Net (adding automatic routing) this will do much of our what our "rewriting" did. I would then use the routes.MapPageRoute to add specific additional page routes (i.e. we would like to get to page x via these additional friendly URLs). Finally, I need some kind of rewriting though if I want to do any external changes (i.e. the old domain to new domain).